# Choosing Hadoop solution for Big Data project - Pricing Options

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have to use Hadoop for my research work and I am deciding for the best option to start with. So far I have end up to go with Cloudera. I've downloaded the [quick start VM](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-3-x.html)
and started learning different [turorials](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/training/roles/developers.html).

The issue is that my system can't afford to run it and perform very slow and I think it might just stop working after I feed it with all the data and run other services.

I was advised to go for a cloud service with 4 cluster node. Can someone please help me by providing the best option and estimated pricing to consider? 1 year plan might be enough to complete my research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are a linux user, Just download the individual components(like hdfs, MR1, YARN, Hbase, Hive etc...) from this  [Cloudera Archives](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/) instead of loading Cloudera Quickstart VM.

If you want to try the 4 node cluster, easiest option is to use cloud. 
There are plenty of cloud providers. I have personally used AWS, Google Cloud, Microsoft Azure, IBM SmartCloud. Out of which, AWS is the best to start with.
It is like pay as you go(use).I can recommend you to use a decent EC2 Machine(4 X m3.large Machines)

Type: m3.large  CPU:2   RAM:7.5G    Storage: 1 x 32 SSD Price: $0.133 per Hour [AWS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

If you plan to do the research for one year, I recommend you to go for VPC.

***Cons of AWS EC2:***
If you launch a machine in EC2, the moment you restart your machine, Your IP and the hostname will get changed.

In AWS VPC, your IP and hostname will remain the same.

**If you use 4 Machinesx24x7xone month,it costs you $389.44**.
You can calculate the [AWS cost](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) by yourself

Comment: Thanks user, AWS calculator really helped. m3.large seems a better option. We will have to ability to stop the services, right? I mean to say that 24x7 is not in my case and what is wrong with a dynamic IP.

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can see you have two paths:

1. Setup Hadoop in a cloud service provider (i.e. Amazon's EC2 or
   Redhat's Openshift.
2. Use Hadoop-as-a-service (i.e. Amazon's EMR or Microsoft's HDInsight).

The first path, setting up Hadoop in a cloud service provider will require you to become a semi-competent Hadoop administrator. If that's your goal, great! However you'll spend a great deal of time learning the necessary skills and mindset to become that. I don't suspect that that is your goal.

The second path is the one I'd recommend out of these two. Using Hadoop-as-a-service you will get up and running faster, but will cost more up front and on an ongoing (per hour basis). You'll still probably save money because you'll be spending less time troubleshooting your Hadoop cluster and more time doing the work you wanted to do in the first place.

I have to wonder, if you can even fit your dataset on your laptop, why are you using big data tools in the first place? True, they'll work. However Big Data is at least partially defined as data sets and computational problems that just don't fit on a single machine.

Comment: Hi Doomy, I think I had already reached that point but thanks for the answer. Initially I have just signed-up for the AWS Free tier account which seems a good starting point but I doubt if EMR is covered under that. Configuring on the laptop was just a staring point which I realized is not gonna work. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to pay money to Amazon regardless. Not much way around that I fear :)